# How to decode JSON string in php?

Tags: php, json, string, decode

Want to decode this json string.

> {"teams":[["Player11","Player27"],["Player28","Player31"],["Player30","Player16"],["Player26","Player6"],["Player4","Player32"],["Player12","Player22"],["Player7","Player10"],["Player17","Player2"],["Player24","Player14"],["Player21","Player3"],["Player25","Player20"],["Player8","Player29"],["Player23","Player13"],["Player15","Player1"],["Player19","Player9"],["Player18","Player5"]],"results":[[[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0],[11,2],[1,2],[1,22],[1,22],[2,22],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1]],[[1,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,2],[2,1],[2,3],[1,2]],[[1,3],[2,1],[2,1],[2,3]],[[1,3],[1,2]],[[1,2],[1,5]]]]}

Comment: You didn't even attempt to *think* about researching this, did you? Asking for help immediately is a sign that someone shouldn't be a programmer.

Comment: try using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: dude google it before u post here

Comment: Agreed with @JohnConde. Just quit programming immediately and save everyone the trouble.

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the doc of json_decode?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode() function of PHP. It will give result in array.